# Difference between template and interface usage?

Tags: c#, templates, interface

I'm trying to code a function, what calles a function from a class what is derived from an interface (ISFAction).

Where is the difference/what is better?

```
  public string Create<T>(ISFServer server, T action, string[] args) where T : ISFAction
  {
      string requestUrl = null; 
      string actionPart = action.GenerateAction(args);
      requestUrl += server.serverUri.ToString();
      requestUrl += "request.php?req=";
      requestUrl += actionPart;

      return requestUrl;
  }
```

And my other version:

```
  public string Create(ISFServer server, ISFAction action, string[] args)
  {
      string requestUrl = null; 
      string actionPart = action.GenerateAction(args);
      requestUrl += server.serverUri.ToString();
      requestUrl += "request.php?req=";
      requestUrl += actionPart;

      return requestUrl;
  }
```

What is better?

Comment: Seeing as using generics here is completely unnecessary, I'd go with the latter. Using generics only adds complexity.

Comment: Note that one commonly says that C# has generics, but not templates. If one talks specifically C++ template vs. C# generics, then both are entirely different, even if they appear similar on first glance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second code snippet (without the generic type argument) is better, because (as you showed in the first code snippet) the generic type argument is useless; it isn't used at all. This just complicates code without a reason.